# Xades signature using xpath/xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xades4j

Can someone post me an examble of a xades4j signature using an xpath or a xslt transformation, if it is possible?

for example: if i have this document:

```
<a>
  <b>text</b>
  <c>zzz</c>
  <b>yyy</b>
</a>
```

i want a xades signature that sign only *b* element(s), thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I haven't seen nothing in the documentation, i don't know if this kind of signature is possible.3

Answer (score 1):

There's a [section on the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/DefiningSignedResources#Transforms) regarding transforms.

Also, there's a [package with algorithm definitions](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/algorithms/package-summary.html), including [XPath transform](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/algorithms/XPathTransform.html), that you can use when defining the signed data objects.

In your example, you probaly would want a `DataObjectReference` with an empty URI (whole document) and then the `XPathTransform` with an expression like /a/b.